# About delete binary logs file on Cloud Sql

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have a question about binary log on Google Cloud Sql.
Now that storage on Cloud SQL is constantly increasing, I want to delete the binary logs files. I have read the documentation about it, but it is not clear that when I disable the binary logs function, will the files be deleted immediately or have to wait for the next 7 days for the files to be deleted. Thank you.
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/pitr#disk-usage

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation :

[Disk usage and point-in-time recovery](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/pitr#disk-usage)

> The binary logs are automatically deleted with their associated
> automatic backup, which generally happens after about 7 days.

[Diagnosing issues with Cloud SQL instances](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues#manually-delete-tips)

> Binary logs cannot be manually deleted.
> Binary logs are automatically deleted with their associated automatic
> backup, which generally happens after about seven days.

Therefore you have to wait for **about 7 days** for the Binary logs and their associated automatic backup to be deleted.